# Best way to implement a Photosharing app

Tags: android, jquery, ios, cordova

I'm doing a photosharing app with account authentication using phonegap.

We will be using jquery(client),CSS3(no-images and animation)/codeigniter(server) and we already structure our database from the server.

I can't decide how should I retrieve my data and what to do with it after I pull it from the server.

I should retrieve the data base from the login that is used it pulls out the friends/followers/people who comment to the pictures just like instagram did but it is more like a combination of facebook and instagram.

The data should be synchronized or auto update everytime there's a new comment from the photos,friend request,etc,.
Should I cache the data when I pull it from the server?What is the best way to CRUD cache data?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you can prefetch some amount of necessary data when the user log in, and you can have a background service to schedule batch transfers and batch update data. It should not automatically sync data everytime (unless you really need it), because internet connections will shorten the battery life rather quickly.

You can read this good document about this: http://developer.android.com/training/efficient-downloads/efficient-network-access.html#PrefetchData

The document is for Android, but I think it can be applied for other platforms.

Hope it help you something :)

Comment: Thanks I could use this to my app.I will prefetch JSON data using jQuery.